# Mixing Threaded Timer and PLINQ

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, plinq

I'm having a problem when calling PLINQ's ForAll Extension in a Threaded Timer Callback. That will create threads indefinitely. The code example is a simple down stripped version of the actual problem.

```
class Program
{
    static List<int> x = new List<int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                   
        x = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).ToList();
        System.Threading.Timer[] timers = new System.Threading.Timer[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            timers[i] = new System.Threading.Timer(ElapsedCallback, null, 1000, 1000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ElapsedCallback(object state)
    {
        int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        x.AsParallel().ForAll(y => Console.WriteLine(y + " - " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - " + id));
    }
}
```

If monitored in the taskmanager one can see that the thread count will raise until the process hangs. If i limit the ThreadPool Size the process will create threads until that size and then gets stuck also.

If seen that pattern in other code also. For example the ConnectionPool in the Firebird ADO.Net Provider does it this way also to clean up unused Connections. If i'm doing something dumb here i'm not the only one ;) Any insights?

Edit : Jim asked for some context so ...

This pattern is used in a Transaction Pool for ReadOnly Transactions. The App might have multiple readonly transactions open in a dozen different Databases. Each database has its own Pool of Transaction and its own Timer that regularly commits and disposes old transactions for that database in the pool. Each transaction commit is then parallelized via PLINQ's ForAll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating 10 timers, each of which is going to tick once per second. It's going to take more than a second for those timers all to output all that data. So then you get the *next* tick for each timer, and more threads will be created that won't complete before the next, and . . . yeah, that's never going to complete.

Even if you did this with just one timer, it's possible that the callback wouldn't complete before the next tick, one second later. If you use a single timer, you can solve the problem in one of several ways:

1. Disabling the timer when you enter the callback, and re-enabling it when you exit. That will prevent (in most cases) ticks from occurring while you're processing a callback. However, there are situations when multiple ticks could still occur, most often when the system is heavily loaded.
2. Create a lock object and use `Monitor.TryEnter` to try to obtain a lock when you enter the callback. If you can't obtain the lock, then exit. Of course, if you do obtain the lock then you'll want to call `Monitor.Exit` before exiting the callback.
3. Make your timer a one-shot so that it triggers just once. When the callback is done with its work, the callback re-initializes the timer, again as a one-shot. This works well, although then your callback is executed one second after the last callback ended, rather than once every second.

Without more information about what you're really trying to do, it's impossible to give more concrete recommendations.

Comment: Unfortunately that makes no difference. I can leave ForAll empty and/or take a longer timer period the thread count will still rise just slower.

Comment: @Ralf: I think the primary problem is that you have 10 timers which combined take more than a second to execute.

Comment: I locked it with a monitor (one for each timer) and that seems to make a difference. Even if i can't see why that should help :( I just tried it (the original code) with an empty ForAll and a period of 5 Seconds. That should never overlapp. I will try some more and will mark this one as the answer afterwards.

Comment: Downvoter? Something specific here you disagree with?

Comment: I measured the TimerCallbacks runtime with a Stopwatch and if more timers then installed cores are used the first callbacks might be really slow. I assume creating the first threads just need that time. If the time was shorter than the timers period alll callbacks after that one are fast as expected if not .... everything gets bad ;) Thanks for pointing into the right direction.

Comment: @Ralf: Yes. The thread pool will wait some amount of time between starting new threads. You can affect that behavior somewhat by calling [ThreadPool.SetMinThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads.aspx), but carefully consider the warnings.